# Calcular colunas no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin

quero realizar uma query onde posso calcular a soma de varias colunas, tentei o código abaixo mais so traz um resultado apenas, na table tenho: comentarios, curtidas,views tenho que fazer a soma de todos eles

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: e qual a dificuldade? pode fazer tanto `sum(coluna1), sum(coluna2), etc` como `sum(coluna1+coluna2+...)`

Answer (score -1):

Tua query está incompleta para o que tu deseja fazer, por isso vem apenas um resultado.

Tenta algo como

SELECT SUM(comentarios) AS totalcomentarios, SUM(curtidas) AS totalcurtidas, SUM(views) AS totalviews FROM links

Esta query deve trazer três valores, um pra cada SUM.